# How to get the rows corespondent to a specific column values using linux command.

Tags: linux

I have an o/p like below.I want the values of first column correspondent to a input value for second column.

Ex: in column 1, 0 and 1 belongs to 0 value of column 2.
So I need a command in which if I pass 0(second column values) I must get 0,1

dmpgdo dbsconfig 0 | grep AMP | grep Online | awk -F' ' '{print $1,$4}'
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 2
6 3
7 3

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

`printf "0 0\n1 0\n2 1\n3 1\n4 2\n5 2\n6 3\n7 3" | awk '{if ($2 == 0) print $1}'
    0
    1`